# silverstripe Sitetree onAfterWrite - renderWith Error: Template not found

Tags: templates, silverstripe

for the automated generation of pdfs from the page content I want to use the renderWith function within onAfterWrite in the Page Class (later with DOMPDF the PDF will be generated from the returned HTML):

```
public function onAfterWrite() {
    parent::onAfterWrite();
    $this->renderPdf();
}
public function renderPdf() {
    return $this->renderWith(array('Pdf'));
}
```

There is always this Error returned when saving the Page: None of these templates can be found in theme 'mytheme': Pdf.ss

The Template exists for sure and calling the Function renderPdf via a Template works perfectly. This is a bit weird. (ss 3.1.1)

many thanks,
florian

EDIT: maybe it is related to 3.1, I just tested in 3.0.5. without any issues. In a clean 3.1.2 install I was able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your template located exactly?
Have you tried to put it under the 'templates' folder, and not under 'Layout' or 'Includes'?
In your case, I would try to move that file here:
/themes/mytheme/templates/Pdf.ss
As you are calling for a standalone template (so not alongside 'Page' for example), the .ss file should be accessible as a 'root' template, as opposed to a layout template.

Comment: hey! I had it in /themes/mytheme/templates/Pdf.ss 
I just tried to put Pdf.ss in /Layout or /Includes - in both cases I can call the renderPdf Function via a Template, but calling it in the onAfterWrite function fails.

Comment: ok. Another thing is that, when in the backend, the theme is not set AFAIK. Do you still get that issue if you place your template under /mysite/templates/Pdf.ss ?

Comment: I had a similar problem, seems like if you are using the onAfterWrite() method you have to place the template in mysite/.. folder. Kinda annoying but hey it works..