# Silverstripe 3 - RenderWith can't find template

Tags: silverstripe

I want to create a PDF with DOMPdf. My PDF Template is located in

```
themes/Template/
themes/Template/templates
themes/Template/templates/Pdf
themes/Template/templates/Layout
```

But I receive a template not found error.

According to this Question [silverstripe Sitetree onAfterWrite - renderWith Error: Template not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224415/silverstripe-sitetree-onafterwrite-renderwith-error-template-not-found#answers) I put the template into `mysite/templates/Pdf` and it works.

**Is there a way to keep the template in the theme folder?**

Here's my code.

```
public function createPdf(){
        $pdf = new SS_DOMPDF();
        
        $data = array(
        
        );
        
        $pdf->setHTML($this->customise($data)->renderWith('InvOffPdf'));
        $pdf->render();
        
        $pdfFilename = str_replace(array(' ', '#'), '', $this->Title) . '.pdf';
        $pdfFolder = 'clientcenter/' . $this->Client()->CID . '-' . $this->Client()->Random;
        
        $pdf->toFile($pdfFilename, $pdfFolder);
        
        $filename = 'assets/' . $pdfFolder . '/' . $pdfFilename;

        $file = File::get()->Filter('Filename', $filename)->First();
        if( $file ){
            $file->ClientID = $this->ClientID;
            $file->ShowInSearch = 0;
            $file->write();
            
            $this->Download = '<a href="' . $filename . '">PDF herunterladen</a>';
            $this->write();
        }
    }
```

**edit:**
I've tried spekulatius' solution. but I've done something wrong.

```
$pdfTemplate = SSViewer::setTemplateFile('Layout', 'InvOffPdf');
$pdf->setHTML($this->customise($data)->renderWith($pdfTemplate));
```

This is the error I receive

```
[Strict Notice] Non-static method SSViewer::setTemplateFile() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you sure `Template` is the active theme? `renderWith` will only look in the theme folder that's currently the active one.

Comment: Yep it is in the active theme

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving *renderWith* a string and Silverstripe searches for the template file itself you could give renderWith a instance of *SS_Viewer* http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SSViewer.html and set the template file you want to use with *setTemplateFile*.

This way you build the Viewer and define how the rendering should look like to avoid Silverstripe looking in the wrong place.

Edit to explain it more detailed. I had more this in mind:

```
$pdfTemplate = new SSViewer();
$pdfTemplate->setTemplateFile('themes/Template/templates/Pdf/InvOffPdf.ss');
$pdf->setHTML($this->customise($data)->renderWith($pdfTemplate));
```

Untested, of course.

Comment: I tried it, and posted my attempt. Could you pls tell me what is wrong?